# In App Billing, further testing

Tags: android, libgdx, in-app-billing

I got my current app in test with some items to testpurchase. And I´ve done that now but I need to do further testing on those items. Is there a way to simply "restore" those purchases so that I dont get that error "You already own this item" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There [is](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html) a [way](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#Consume):

> Once an in-app product is purchased, it is considered to be "owned".
>   In-app products in the "owned" state cannot be purchased from Google
>   Play. **You must send a consumption request for the "owned" in-app
>   product before Google Play makes it available for purchase again.**
>   Consuming the in-app product reverts it to the "unowned" state, and
>   discards the previous purchase data.